# VirtualBox Ubuntu Bridged Network not working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-http-server

I have an Ubuntu 15.10 VirtualBox installed on Windows 10.

First, I should say that it was working, but after configuring apache and running `apt-get update`, I noticed that the bridged network isn't working as when the IP of VBox wasn't responding. Here's my current `ifconfig`.

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:0f:cf:6d  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:488 (488.0 B)  TX bytes:24553 (24.5 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ec:d2:7a  
          inet addr:10.0.3.15  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feec:d27a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8201 (8.2 KB)  TX bytes:21781 (21.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:27906 (27.9 KB)  TX bytes:27906 (27.9 KB)
```

the `sudo ufw status` says `Status: inactive` and the host windows firewall is allowed for the VirtualBox software.

I need to know how to diagnose this never ending "Connecting" connection that I see in ubuntu. Is there any error log file or an actual solution please?

Comment: What happens if you run the 'dhclient' command in your VM?

Comment: @Richie086 dhclient returns
`RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`
`RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @Richie086 I just added sudo, it returns `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`

Comment: Hmm strange.  After running dhclient, run ifconfig to see if it picks up an IP address from DHCP.

Comment: i've tried again and it didn't, I'm constantly looking at the networking icon that indicates "connecting".

Comment: What is enp0s8?  That seems to have an IP address.

Comment: This is a VirtualBox, I gave it NAT and Bridged. the NAT always has an IP, it's the Bridged that had an IP, but not anymore. Disabling the NAT doesn't help, just takes the internet out. Also I can't access that IP from the host OS, any sort of access from host to the virtual machine would solve my problem though

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual solution for the Bridged Network.
I used **Host-only Adapter** instead and it did the job for me. Now I have access to the Apache web server through web browser (HTTP) and also the guest's shared folder (full permission).

Instead of `192.168.1.7`, now it's `192.168.56.101`.

I'd still love to hear a solution or explanation for the Bridged Network.